# How do you change the output volume of a sound?

Tags: android, audio, notificationmanager

I'm using this code to play a sound.

I would like to give the user the ability to alter the volume of the sound. Can you tell me how to do this?

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification();
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://emad/raw/quarter");
```

Thanks.

Truly,
Emad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
  notification.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;

  context.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: Hi Nammari, Thanks for the fast reply. Can you tell me how to change the volume to 50%  ? Truly, Emad

Comment: Hi Nammari, I also found that when I typed the full stop after context the setVolumeControlStream was not in the intellisense and Eclipse showed an error that said "The method setVolumeControlStream(int) is undefined for the type Context"

Comment: fo the 50% volume see 

AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume/2, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);



note : this is untested code for more information how to set the volume of stream [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int, int, int))

Comment: Hi Nammari, It's in a BroadcastReceiver. I will try the other code you showed to see how it works. Thanks. Truly, Emad

Comment: Hi Nammari, The code works perfectly. I also figured out how to retail the original volume so I can restore it after adjusting it. I do have one more question. I noticed FLAG_PLAY_SOUND. Is there a way to call STREAM_MUSIC without making a sound or vibration? That would be ideal. If there is none, I will be ok with just the vibration until my user complain. Thanks. Truly, Emad

Comment: lsn u can use FLAG_SHOW_UI Show a toast containing the current volume.
just showing a toast will look great , if i answered u can check my question near the voting :)

Comment: Hi Nammari, I will use that. Truly, Emad